# (Blender Internal) Easy way to have an object shoot fire?

Tags: animation

I'm trying to animate Godzilla shooting fire. I'm relatively new to the particle system, so what I did was I went in edit mode, selected the center of the throat, and clicked P and selected "by loose parts", and added a particle system to that mouth selection. Here was the result:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTd3kWEchrU

It looks really, really bad. For starters, the origin of it is going through Godzilla's head. It overall just looks very bad, I want to add a more flame-like look to it. Something like the original in this scene (starts at 0:44):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VqgdWu4IvfM

Also can you guys give me something that won't kill my system or pay at 2 frames. Thanks so much!

Comment: I know that posting links to solution isn't great idea, but in this situation I don't see the point to reinventing the weel so here you go exactly what you want: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-flamethrower/

Comment: Ah okay thank you for letting me know. I'm going to be asking a few more questions which I couldn't really find anywhere else, so thank you!

Comment: Blender internal isn't my thing, but I would always try. If you have more questions regarding this topic feel free to ask them here in updates and let me know about it in comments.